# How to stop a system update upon restart

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat, 8.0-oreo, downgrade

I have an old Essential PH-1 that runs on Android 7.1.1 (Nougat).

I accidentally okay'ed it to update to Oreo and it says to allow the updates to take effect to the newer Oreo OS I need to restart my phone. I do NOT want to update to the new OS. I want to keep Nougat OS.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Is there a way to erase these new files so that a restart will not finish installing the update to Oreo?
Or do I have to let it update upon restart and then downgrade (back to Nougat)?
If so, where do I go to find the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your device "Developer options".

In case it is not there then:

- Click your device build number 7 times.

Then in "Developer options":

- Disable "Automatic system updates"

[image]